# How do I classify unlabelled dataset using weka API for java?

Tags: java, classification, weka, text-classification

I am currently trying to classify tweets based in sentiment (positive, negative, neutral). I have trained my naive Bayes using a training dataset...

```
NaiveBayes nb = new NaiveBayes();
nb.buildClassifier(trainingData);
```

I have tried labelling my unlabelled data using the following code

```
Instances unlabeled = new Instances(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
            "C:/Users/me/Desktop/unlabelled.ARFF")));       
unlabeled.setClassIndex(unlabeled.numAttributes()-1);

//create copy
Instances labeled = new Instances(unlabeled);

for(int i = 0 ; i < unlabeled.numInstances() ; i++) {       
    double clsLabel = nb.classifyInstance(unlabeled.instance(i));
    labeled.instance(i).setClassValue(clsLabel);
}
```

However I am not getting correct output for example if I declare the class as {positive, negative, neutral} it will always assign positive.

Has anyone any experience on this? I am using weka api in java.

Comment: try printing `clsLabel` in every iteration. Is it always the same number?

Comment: @xro7 yeh its always the same number. If I change the order of my class to {negative, positive, neutral} it will just use the first type (negative). Have you any experience with classifying unclassified datasets using weka api?

Comment: Yes i have.Your code seems fine though. There might be a problem with your classifier. Another way to check this is to use `double[] labelArray = nb.distributionForInstance(unlabeled.instance(i));` and then print the probability for each class for every attribute. If the other classes have zero probability then its almost certain a classifer issue.

Comment: Did you cross validate your classifier? Were your results satisfying?

Comment: @xro7 I think I have sorted out the problem. I am now faced with a new one, When I write the newly classified dataset to an ARFF file it is all over the place. Any ideas how solve this problem?

Comment: need more info about the issue. what do you mean all over the place?